# How do I get the data from a jplot graph on a website

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, jqplot

I'm trying to get the data from a graph at https://www.learner.org/wp-content/interactive/envsci/ecology/ecology.html(to show the graph you can just press All on and then the run button) I've tried looking at the java script and html as well as using inspect and looking at the sources but I haven't been able to find anything linking to the graph any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What the exact data do you want? You want to counts animals or what?

Comment: @ulou Yeah just the total population for each animal at each day